# Fried pies lose their shape

Tags: frying

Family recipe for Vollinas.

- 4-5 cups flour
- 4 egg yolks
- 1 cup milk
- 1 pkg yeast
- 1 stick sweet cream butter
- 1/2 cup sugar.

After mixing & kneading & rising overnight, golf ball size pieces are pulled off, rolled out into an oval shape, filled with nuts, & folded over into a pie shape. The edges are sealed. When fried in oil they tend to increase in size & lose their fried pie shape. Any thoughts why they increase in size & how to remedy that?

Comment: Do they behave the same when other family members make them?

Comment: I'm the only maker.

Answer (score 2):

"Filled with nuts" and "edges are sealed" - this is normal to happen with such a food. The filling produces steam, which blows up the pie. You should use less filling and pierce it in a place or two before frying, so you'll have less steam, and what is in there will escape.

Answer (score 0):

You should try freezing them before frying. I saw thats how Momofuku Milk bar does it.